# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 in List Map

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, hashmap

In my app, I would like to have a listView with pie chart. This is the [pie_chart](https://pub.dev/packages/pie_chart/example) library I'm using.

But I get error in `List<Map<String,double>>`.

```
List<Map<String, double>> map = List<Map<String, double>>();

 ListView.builder(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var item = data[index];
            map[index].putIfAbsent("< 1 Weeks ago>", () => (2.0));
            return PieChart(
                     ...
                dataMap: map[index],
                     ...
            )
    }
```

**Error**

```
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
```

The error pointed to   `map[index].putIfAbsent("< 1 Weeks ago>", () => (2.0));`. What is wrong here?

Comment: what does data have? is it not null when the ListView.builder runs?

Comment: @JaimeOrtiz data not null..I can get `item[index]` without no issue, but after added `map[index]`, the error persist.

Comment: Why are you using in the itemCount `data.length` instead of `map.length`. And what is this `data` variable?

Comment: maybe the list bulder throws an error because there are more elements inside data than in map, and it tries to access an index in map that does not exists

Comment: @croxx5f question edited. The map length should be always same with `data.length`.

Comment: @JaimeOrtiz Intersting. So how am I going to add the elements into `Map`?

Comment: i added an answer, i think that does what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add each of the elements from data and add them to map i did this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List map = [];

    List data = [
      {'entry_1': 1},
      {'entry_2': 2},
      {'entry_3': 3}
    ];

    return MaterialApp(
      title: MyApp._title,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var item = data[index];
            map.add(item);
            return Container(
              height: 100,
              child: Text('Entry: ${map[index]}'),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

this takes the list of maps "data", grabs each value and add it to the list "map" and then builds a list of containers with a text widget containing the corresponding entry that map took from data

Comment: thanks for your answer but `dataMap` should take `<Map<String,double>>`.

Comment: Thats great, how did you do it?

Comment: I bad on explanation, have provided my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Was managed to fix it based on @Jamie's clue

```
ListView.builder(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: analytic.unitOwnerByWorkOrderCount.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var item = data[index];
            Map<String, double> map = Map<String, double>();
            List<Map<String, double>> list = List<Map<String, double>>();

            map.putIfAbsent("< 1 Weeks ago>",
                () => (item['less_one_weeks_ago'].toDouble()));
            list.add(map);
                 ....

           return PieChart(
               dataMap: list[index];
                 ....
           )
  }
```